# @include makes empty line above my navbar

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to include script in head of every blade.php. I tried that with @include but then that makes and empty row above mine navbar. That script doesn't contain anything else but .
Here is the screenshot.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPvfS.jpg)

Here is the code.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company listing</title>
    @include('includes.script');
  </head>
```

Comment: add your include script code

Comment: Have you hardcoded that script in there instead of the @include to see if it still has a space?

Comment: @emotality When i hardcode it there isn't empty raw.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. When you put ';' at the end of include it will add that empty row. After deleting it there is no more empty row.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company listing</title>
    @include('includes.script')
  </head>
```